# How to put button in up-right corner?

Tags: html, css, alignment

How can i put a button in up-right corner? I was trying a lot of CSS things, but i really can't understand them, and they doesn't work. Can someone tell me something simple and that works? Here is HTML & CSS of my button.

HTML: < a href="#" class="myButton">green< /a>
CSS: http://www.stefanpage.ml/questions/css-1.html

Every answer is useful! :)

[This is how i mean that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtvl2.jpg)

Answer (score 15):

```
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
right: 10px;
```

Comment: Only thing I would add is z-index : 999;

Answer (score 9):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
.myButton {

    padding: 30px;
    display:block;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6dg8nc4u/

Please mark as correct answer if that's what you are looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: Whoah! I didn't know that is so easy! Thank you so much! You helped my site to grow up! :)

Comment: I will when i get 15+ reputation...I am new here ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
.myButton {
    position: fixed; /* or position: absolute; */
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

That is only the code for the positioning. All other styling is left out.